# javafx 11 does not find the main class from which it was called from

Tags: eclipse-plugin, classloader, javafx-11

I am trying to launch the application from an eclipse product definition.
I have synchronized the product with its defining plug in, and in "contents" I hit "all required plugins".

The stack trace tells it all. Of course the package is correct.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.rulez.demokracia.zenta3.editor.ZentaApplication
    at javafx.application.Application.launch(Application.java:304)
    at org.rulez.demokracia.zenta3.editor.ZentaApplication.run(ZentaApplication.java:41)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.callMethodWithException(EclipseAppContainer.java:592)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:661)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1476)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1449)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.rulez.demokracia.zenta3.editor.ZentaApplication
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:190)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.ContextFinder.loadClass(ContextFinder.java:135)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:374)
    at javafx.application.Application.launch(Application.java:292)
    ... 19 more
```

the ZentaApplication class is public, and everything is exported from all plugins.
The product file lies in the same project as the class.

Javafx libraries are exported from a plugin specifically created for this purpose, and it is of course a dependency of the main plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Moving the libraries from the dependency plugin right into the main plugin have helped. My hypothesis is that the main class was not available from the dependency package.